# DRF Update price of a product via Viewset Interface

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My model for this is straight simple, but I fail to create a "handsome" interface on the ViewSet Template:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    pid = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique = True)
    price = models.DecimalField(Price, default = 0)
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128)
```

I created a serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["pid", "name", "price"]
```

and I added a `ViewSet`:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    http_methods = ["get", "put"] 

    def list(self, request):
        query = Product.objects.all()
        results = ProductSerializer(data = query, many = True)
        results.is_valid()
        return Response(data = results.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def put(self, request):
        serializer = LoadPageSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            P = Product.objects.get(id = request.data["pid"])
            P.price = request.data["price"]
            P.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

the current urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'product', views.ProductViewSet, basename = "product")

urlpatterns = [url('^api/', include(router.urls)),]
```

[image]

If I execute this, when I choose a new price I run into the unique constraint of the `pid` field: `product with this id already exists.`.

EDIT: ID was a poorly chosen extra field, it is just a value that comes from a different database.

Comment: why do you crate id field django already creates one for you ??

Comment: Django by default adds a unique id field to all models. Why don't you let django manage the field for you?

From django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/):
`An id field is added automatically, but this behavior can be overridden`

Answer (score 1):

The function in your view should be called update not put `def put(self, request):` should be `def update(self, request):`

- you should use the serializer_class in every function the ViewSet
- remove `http_methods = ["get", "put"]`  there is no need for it ... it will be automatically generated or you can add them to your `.as_view()`

this is they way DRF works https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewsets

---

if you want to override the id field django provide you should add `primary_key=True` into your field `id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)` but i don't know why you want to do that ?? if you want to make your custom id field you can change the name of the field to any thing else like `custom_id`

docs :[overriding the id field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Comment: I changed the method to `update` but now I do not get any form to put data into on the api route page. Do I need to edit the `http_method_names` or something else? (I also changed the ID thing in my post (was just a placeholder I poorly chose).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still I do not see any kind of form on my template page with `update ...`. I added my `urls.py`.